# Calling a method on a variable and stopping a loop before reaching threshold

Tags: javascript

I'm reading Kyle Simpson's YDKJS and this was the first exercise after the first chapter. We were to write a program that finds the value of a phone + tax and purchase a certain amount of phones + accessories below a given threshold.

A couple of questions.

1) Is there a way to call the toFixed method on a var without having to build it into a function? Meaning can I build that formatting function then just call it on a variable when I'm going to console.log it.

2) If I place 'moneyInBank = moneyInBank - amount;' into the loop, why does it spit out a negative number? Does this have to deal with scopes? Is it creating a new variable inside the loop instead of changing the balance at the global level?

I wanted to go slightly beyond what was required like. 
- Stop the loop if adding 1 more phone breaks the threshold. Instead, it went above the threshold. In this case, do I need to use some type of remainder expression?

```
const spendingThreshold = 1500;
const priceOfPhone = 150;
const priceOfAcc = 20;
const salesTax = .08;

var moneyInBank = 2500;
var amount = 0;

function tax(amount) {
        return amount * salesTax;
}

function costOfPhone(){
   return(priceOfPhone + priceOfAcc) + ((priceOfPhone + priceOfAcc) * salesTax);
}

/* We are running a conditional using the 'while' loop to run when the amount is less than the var spendingThreshold.
We then change the amount variable by adding 'amount' + the costOfPhone. costOfPhone takes in the price of the phone + taxes already, so there is no need for a taxes function. However, if we wanted to we could create a taxFunction
to be called on other products as well and not just on the phones.

*/

while (amount < spendingThreshold){
    amount = amount + costOfPhone();
    if(amount > spendingThreshold)
        console.log("You cannot afford another phone!");
}

function formatAmount(){
  return "$" + amount.toFixed(2);
}


moneyInBank = moneyInBank - amount;

function formatMoneyBank(){
  return "$" + moneyInBank.toFixed(2);
}

console.log("The cost of each phone + tax is $" + costOfPhone());
console.log("The cost of your total purcahase is " + formatAmount(amount));
console.log("You have " + formatMoneyBank(moneyInBank) + " left in your bank account!");
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question number one, you may display monetary values in javascript like so:

```
moneyInBank.toLocaleString('en', {style: "currency", currency: "USD"})
```

This works for all variables whose type is 'number' and leverages the internationalization capabilities of your browser. Of course, you could also define

```
const format = funds => `$${Number(funds).toFixed(2)}`
```

and invoke it like so `format(5)` or even so `format("6.0")`.

For your second question, there is no issue with scopes. You just need to revise the logic. In particular, the loop does not seem to `break` when the threshold is exceeded and does not require the bank account to have sufficient funds `moneyInBank >= amount`.